# Update colorbar/coloraxis position - Plotly Python

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I’m trying to update the position of a colobar/axis from a Choropleth map.

I found on the plotly forum that it was possible to do it with the following line, but nothing happened for me:

```
fig.update_layout(coloraxis_colorbar_x=-0.15)
```

I also tried this:

```
fig.data[0].colorbar.x=-0.1
```

It’s almost working with this method, but when I clicked on my update button, the colorbar is going back to it’s original position (on the right, obviously).

Here is my code:

```py
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df =pd.DataFrame(np.array([['Germany', 2, 3], ['United States', 5, 6], ["Italy", 8, 9]]),
                   columns=['country', 'data_a', 'data_b'])

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Choropleth(
    locations = df['country'],
    z = df['data_a'],
    text = df['country'],
    colorscale = 'Teal',
    autocolorscale=False,
    reversescale=False,
    marker_line_color='black',
    marker_line_width=0.3,
    colorbar_title = '<b>data_a_title</b>',
    locationmode ='country names'
))

#update map style
fig.update_layout(
    geo=dict(
        showframe=False,
        showcoastlines=True,
        projection_type='equirectangular'
    )
)
 

#dropdown menu
button1 =  dict(method = "update",
                args = [{'z': [ df["data_a"] ] ,
                       "colorbar":{"title":{"text":"title_a"} }}],
                label = "data_a")
button2 =  dict(method = "update",
                args = [{'z': [ df["data_b"] ],
                       "colorbar":{"title":{"text":"title_b"} }}],
                label = "data_b")


fig.update_layout(width=700,
                  coloraxis_colorbar_thickness=23,
                  updatemenus=[dict(y=0.2,
                                    x=1,
                                    xanchor='right',
                                    yanchor='bottom',
                                    active=0,
                                    buttons=[button1, button2])
                              ]) 

fig.show(config={"displayModeBar": False, "showTips": False})
```

I have been trying several things around the args to keep the same position but nothing worked so far.

Any idea about how to do it?

Thank you

Comment: I'm on `'4.14.3'` and your code works exactly as expected wirh `fig.data[0].colorbar.x=-0.1` as the colorbar is displayed on the left hand side for both dropdown options.

Comment: I just updated the code, there was a mistake with the two buttons, the title was not updating at all. The issue is coming from here, I noticed that when the title of the colobar doesn't change, the colorbar keep the same position.

Comment: What version are you running? And *how*? JupyterLab? Something else?

Comment: Running on '4.14.3', I have been trying on JupyterLab & Flask

Comment: How about setting it to the left for each data? `fig.data[0].colorbar.x=-0.1;fig.data[1].colorbar.x=-0.1`

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible. `fig.data[1]` is out of range because the buttons will only update `fig.data[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. To keep the same position when clicking on the button. Be sure to add the following line to set the original position:

```py
fig.data[0].colorbar.x=-0.1
```

And regarding the button update, you will need to set the new x position like this:

```py
button1 =  dict(method = "update",
                args = [{'z': [ df["data_a"] ] ,
                       "colorbar":{"title":{"text":"title_a"}, 'x':-0.1 }}],
                label = "data_a")
button2 =  dict(method = "update",
                args = [{'z': [ df["data_b"] ],
                       "colorbar":{"title":{"text":"title_b"}, 'x':-0.1 }}],
                label = "data_b")
```